# Align column heading to data in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to make a table in HTML , however the "c" column heading does not align with its data, and is instead grouping up with the "b" column heading.

Output:

[image: Table with incorrect table headings]

Here is the code:

```css
table,th,td{
  padding:20px;
  border:10px solid navy;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td colspan="30">Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </td></form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td colspan="30">Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </td></form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td colspan="30">Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </td></form>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
```

I tried changing the values of padding in the `<th>` tag for "c" and "b" , but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your HTML is invalid, since you are have the closing `</td>` before the closing `</form>`. It should be like `</form></td>`

Comment: th has to be wrapped inside a tr . there is 3 of them (first row, the browsers tryes to fix the missing tr), other rows are amade of 32 columns, your second td is spanning 30 columns !!! Look at any basic table tutorial, to generate a valid structure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to solve your problem.

1. Make sure your HTML is valid. Your HTML is currently invalid, since you are have the closing `</td>` before the closing `</form>`. It should be like `</form></td>`.
2. Remove `colspan="30"` attribute from every `td`, change it like:

```html
<td colspan="30">Apples</td>
```

to

```html
<td>Apples</td>
```

`colspan` indicates for how many columns the cell extends. Now it was extending for 30 columns, and you don't have that many columns. [Read more at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

```html
<html>
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 10px solid navy;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <table>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
        </form>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
          <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML so the form closes properly:

```
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="30">Apples</td>
        <td><form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
        </form></td>
    </tr>
```

Today's browsers are very smart and can render invalid HTML, but in order to have control about how your HTML is rendered, you should always use valid Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <style>
        table,th,td{
  padding:20px;
  border:10px solid navy;
}
    </style>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th width="15%">a</th>
            <th width="70%">b</th>
            <th width="15%">c</th>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Apples</td>
                <td><form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>0.5Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="50g"/>1Kg
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bag"/>Paper Bag?
                </form></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello Mihir,
Below code help on screenwise check it I think got results 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a few tutorials about HTML `<table>` to help you build them and understand the use of `rowspan` and `colspan` .
here is a few https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table  https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/  https://html.com/tags/table/ & plenty more via your search engine :)

Fixing your code with missing tag, removing unneeded attributes and closing the form/td properly , you could have done that structure :

```css
table,
th,
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid navy;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>
          <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>
          <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>
          <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />0.5Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="50g" />1Kg
            <input type="checkbox" name="bag" />Paper Bag?
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Have fun learning.